# Toggle with different show/hide speeds

Tags: jquery

Is there a simple way to `.toggle()` with a different show and hide speed?

Can you do something like this:

```
$('.div').toggle(200,100);
```

To Mimic This:

```
$('.div').show(200);
$('.div').hide(100);
```

Comment: Nope, there is nothing about such behaviour in [docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: You could execute a function to return the duration for the toggle.   Something like this.   `$('.div').toggle(getMyDuration(), someCompleteFunction());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no support for doing something like that with `.toggle()`.

You could however, come up with your own jQuery plugin that will carry out your desired behaviour.

Notice I've only called `.show()` in the callback function of `.hide()` to avoid unnecessary queueing.

```
$.fn.myToggle = function(h, s){
    return this.each(function(){
        $(this).hide(h, function(){ $(this).show(s); }) 
    });
};

$('div').myToggle(200, 100);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hh8umcr6/1/)

Comment: Thank you I will accept the answer as soon as I can

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to do what you're doing for your example, use the individual show and hide.

Answer (score 0):

Use something similar to:

```
$('.div').show(200, function () {
    $('.div').hide(100);
});
```